# log backup file disk size issue in MSSQL 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup-strategies, ldf

I have a problem about managing ldf file's size. Db's recovery mode is Full. So ldf file is reached at 360 gb. I want to decrease it by performing log backup. But currently disk does not have 360 gb free space. So backup file is growing continuously.

I tried perform backup to be sure and as i expected, it raises error which says that  there is no enough space in disk.

1. dont have chance to increase disk size
2. Cant change Recovery mode to simple due to database is very important
3. Cant split backup file into different disks. Because there is no
   360 gb space in total of all disks.

What can i do to decrease LDF file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

take a look on this, might help you: http://www.karaszi.com/sqlserver/info_large_transaction_log_file.asp

Comment: it is recommended in article that  backup the log file(i tried already), change recovery model to simple and set full again.(it is a customer restriction for now. I need to find another solution like delete records older than 3 month etc)